# PHP: Curl not called URL and got Error No =0

Tags: php, curl

I am developing one SMS application. I have to call one link 
for eg http://sendsms.com/send.php?mobile=45455&msg=hello for sending SMS

so I used CURL concept to send sms.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15, // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 15, // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
    $header = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    $output ="Error:".$err." ErrMsg:".$errmsg." Header:".  json_encode($header);
```

The Problem is message is not sending. I checked the SMS API server. And There also no request is received. So the only problem is CURL may not calling the server. I tried to print the Error msg and I got `curl_errno($ch) is 0`

please provide me the best way to do this

Comment: Maybe you could set `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to 1 and see if it says something.

Comment: Is the URL you're generating for the post correct? Are you forgetting to pass in your API key for authentication so  the remote system is blocking you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send request by POST:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
```

Comment: Cna you explain why you think this is a solution?